# Can't browse websites on IE8 - Scripts won't load

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

[image][image]I'm trying to access a website (uol.com.br) on Internet Explorer 8, but it doesn't load properly.

It looks defaced, menus won't load, navigation is not possible.

It's not a problem on the website, as I can browse it from different browsers (Firefox, Chrome etc.) But I need to be able to browse it on Internet Explorer 8.

Any idea?

Windows 7 Professional / Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: **There isn't a solution to this problem except to upgrade to a supported version of IE.** IE8 has not been supported for years, the website likely does not support IE8, due to it being unsupported for years.  What you describe is typically when a web developer does something a browser doesn't understand.

Comment: @Ramhound it worked fine a few weeks ago, before this computer get reformatted. Also, this computer is used by a very young man, who only knows to use IE. Moving to a different one isn't easy for him.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Reach out to the website in question.  It working a few weeks ago doesn't really tell us anything except it used to work.  A website's continued support of an **unsupported insecure** browser is never guarantee

Comment: Check Control Panel, Internet Options, Advanced under Browsing and make sure two Disable Scripts... are enabled (checked) and the one below (Display an error) is unchecked.   If that does not help, you will have to upgrade IE to V11

Comment: @John is it possible to use IE 11 on Win 7?

Comment: Absolutely.  I have a Windows 7 Pro virtual machine here and it is running IE 11

Comment: True. I'm already installing it. Thank you. I hope only IE 11 is enough to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john), [in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1519029/cant-browse-websites-on-ie8-scripts-wont-load#comment2299847_1519029), the solution was to update IE8 to the latest version.

Updating to IE11 has fixed the problem.